# Mulitplatform application crashes with System.BadImageFormatException in Relase mode but works fine in Debug

Tags: c#, 64-bit, badimageformatexception

I have an application that I've recently had to add a mixed platform (some 32-bit some 64-bit) component to.  For the 64-bit build, one .exe is 32-bit, the rest are 64-bit, and all the DLLs are set to "Any CPU" (because they need to be shared between both platforms).  Everything works just fine when I compile in Debug.  The 64-bit applications works, the 32-bit application works, and they share all the DLLs no problem.  When I change to Release mode I get a System.BadImageFormatException when trying to start the 64-bit application (note the 32-bit component runs fine).  The error is as follows:

```
System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled
  FileName=XXXXXXXXX.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = XXXXXXXXX.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/company/branches/product/2.6/product/product/bin/Release/x64/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : product, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\company\branches\product\2.6\product\product\bin\Release\x64\product.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///D:/company/branches/product/2.6/product/product/bin/Release/x64/XXXXXXXXX.Framework.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

  HResult=-2147024885
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXXXXXX.Framework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
  Source=product
  StackTrace:
       at product.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at product.App.Main() in D:\company\branches\product\2.6\product\product\obj\x64\Release\App.g.cs:line 51
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Now, when I compare the configurations in the Configuration Manager, they are identical except for the fact that one is Release and the other is Debug.

Debug build configuration:

[image]

Release build configuration:

[image]

All the rest of the projects farther down the list are dlls and are set to "Any CPU" in both configurations.  **Why the heck doesn't this work in release?** It just doesn't make any sense.  I'm almost tempted to release the Debug version since it works exactly the way I want it to.  I've checked the following stack questions for my answer, but they are just slightly different.  Plus, I don't have the option of being able to just build in only 32-bit.  I require both platforms, but the 64-bit fails for some reason.

- [Troubleshooting BadImageFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996653/troubleshooting-badimageformatexception)
- [System.BadImageFormatException occurred when build in Release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719339/system-badimageformatexception-occurred-when-build-in-release-mode)

Comment: The "platform" column is irrelevant to managed projects.  The only thing that matters are the settings in Project > Properties > Compile tab.  The sane way to organize your solution is to *only* keep the AnyCPU platform, a pretty accurate description of what managed code can do.  And you'll have to fix the project that has its Compile tab settings wrong, be sure that a DLL project always has Platform target = AnyCPU and Prefer 32-bit unticked.  For *both* the Debug and the Release configuration.  Only the EXE project decides what jitter is going to be used.

Comment: Wow.  Out of the 30 or so projects,  under the project->properties->build tab, a handful of the projects did not have the same platform selected in both platform combo boxes.  Wonder how long that booby trap was waiting for me.