# Hangfire server unable to pick jobs when Windows service is hosted in release mode

Tags: c#, windows-services, hangfire, badimageformatexception

I am hosting hangfire server inside [Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) so that when my ps starts hangfire server starts automatically and start executing job.

Now the problem is when I host my Windows service in `debug mode` as well as my shared library which contains code to execute long running jobs in `debug mode` then everything is fine i.e hangfire is able to pick up and execute the job.

But when I **host my Windows service as well as shared library in release mode** then I get this below error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary1.SharedLibrary,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

My Windows service is running on `LocalSystem` and my database resides on colleague computer.

**Code :**

```
public partial class MyNewService1 : ServiceBase
        {
            private BackgroundJobServer _server;
            private System.Diagnostics.EventLog eventLog1;
            public MyNewService1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
                if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                        "MySource", "MyNewLog");
                }
                eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
                eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("connectionstring"); 
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart", EventLogEntryType.Information);
                _server = new BackgroundJobServer();
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
                _server.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

I have taken code from following reference: http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-windows-service.html

On docs nothing is mention like whether I should host Windows service in debug/release mode.

Is this a Windows service or hangfire problem?

**Update :** I think problem is related to Windows service as describe here but still no luck:

[System.BadImageFormatException occurred when build in Release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719339/system-badimageformatexception-occurred-when-build-in-release-mode)

Comment: Accepted answer on the question you linked describes it pretty well. Did you try it?

Comment: @Evk Yes i tried that as well as had to changes account type.I have posted answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was related to permission and i have to change from `LocalSystem`  to `NetworkService` so that it assign right of `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

With this i have follow answer given on this below link which solved my problem :

[System.BadImageFormatException occurred when build in Release Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719339/system-badimageformatexception-occurred-when-build-in-release-mode)